# How can i convert a .ARFF file to CSV in Pycharm using a Mac?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, pycharm, arff

Im new to data analysis and looking for help. I converted an .arff file to csv using Pycharm but I am not sure that I did in the right way. Is it possible, right? If so how? Also when I tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd
data_frame = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
```

I got an error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/cristinamulas/PycharmProjects/exam/exam_p.py", line 53, in 
>       data_frame = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
>     File "/Users/cristinamulas/exam/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
>       return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>     File "/Users/cristinamulas/exam/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 440, in _read
>       parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
>     File "/Users/cristinamulas/exam/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 787, in **init**
>       self._make_engine(self.engine)
>     File "/Users/cristinamulas/exam/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1014, in _make_engine
>       self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
>     File "/Users/cristinamulas/exam/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1708, in **init**
>       self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
>     File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 384, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.**cinit**
>     File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 695, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
>   FileNotFoundError: File b'train.csv' does not exist

Comment: is the file `train.csv` is the same directory as your python file? If not, specify the full path to the file.

Comment: I specidicated the full path and it works.Thanks Chris!